# Bootstrap 4 toggle button (hamburger) is not working in fresh Laravel 7 project

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

I installed a new laravel 7 project with auth and created a simple template with bootstrap studio.
After integrating the template into the laravel project everything runs perfectly, except for the toggle menu (hamburger), which does not expand.

The strange thing is, if I integrate the bootstrap and jquery cdn again, although these are included in the app.js by default, the toggle menu works:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Can it be that a reduced version of bootstrap and jquery is included in laravel or what could this be?

Comment: `although these are included in the app.js by default` what makes you say that?

Comment: Because I installed the laravel project with Auth: laravel new blog --auth

Comment: and since I installed it with auth, vue and bootstrap are automatically integrated (bootstrap, jquery, popper and vue are included in my laravel mix & this is also visible in the package.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on github. It was reported there and it appears to be due to jquery and can be resolved by downgrading jquery from version 3.5.0 to 3.4.1.

https://github.com/laravel/ui/issues/91

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 7 doesn't come with Bootstrap by default. You have to specifically install laravel/ui composer package and then install bootstrap fontend scaffolding.

1) Install laravel/ui package:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

2) Generate bootstrap scaffolding:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Or, if you use Laravel Authentication:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

3) Don't forget to compile your assets with Laravel mix once you're done:

```
npm run dev
```

---

**Note:** Since jQuery is a dependency of Bootstrap 4, it will be automatically installed with the Bootstrap scaffolding and compiled in your `js/app.js` file.

More info about Laravel frontend:

- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#introduction

Comment: As I said, I directly involved auth in the project installation: laravel new blog --auth.
Therefore, vue and bootstrap are automatically integrated (bootstrap, jquery, popper and vue are included in my laravel mix & this is also visible in the package.json).
From Bootstrap, everything works, except for opening the hamburgers.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you compile with `npm run dev`?